# How to mix HTML with @If without a Paragraph or Span (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I mix @If with html without using Span Or P or any type of grouping html tags?

```
 @if (Model.AlternateName != null)
    {
    @Model.Name has an alternative name, @(Model.AlternateName).
    }
```

It errors because its expecting ; but

```
 @if (Model.AlternateName != null)
    {
    <span>@Model.Name has an alternative name, @(Model.AlternateName).</span>
    }
```

works but I ideally do not want span, there's a p tag at the top just before so don't want to imbed a p tag.

Comment: You could use `@string.Format("{0} has an alternative name, {1}", Model.Name, Model.AlternateName)`

Answer (score 1):

Try the @: syntax, like this:

```
@if (true)
{
    @: Look mom, no tags! :-)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, I amended it slightly to match my code.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped. Don't forget to "mark as answer" so that it helps others too :)